# How to distinguish between the "se" in "V-se" and "se" in "cómo se (uno) va"? And how to use them both in one sentence?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, verbo-pronominal, oraciones-impersonales

"Se" can be used as impersonal, as a substitute for "uno"

```
cómo se va a la plaza?
```

And "se" can be used as a part of a verb, for instance:

```
se fue él
```

Questions:

1. How to distinguish between them?

**And also**

2. How do I use them both in one sentence?

For instance:

```
 cómo se [uno] se marcha [marcharse] a Roma?
```

Next to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How to distinguish between them?

When "se" is an impersonal pronoun, there is no subject:

- **Se** va a la plaza cruzando la avenida. (You go/One goes to the square by crossing the avenue.)

When "se" is used for the verb to be pronominal (in which case "irse" means "leave"), there needs to be a subject:

- ¿Cómo **se** va **uno** de una fiesta cuando no está cómodo? (How does one leave a party when one doesn't feel at ease?)

> 2) How do I use them both in one sentence? (Good question!)

There is no overlapping of *se*'s. You need to use a subject, either express (*uno*) or tacit (*tú*):

- ¿Cómo **se** va **uno** de una fiesta cuando no está cómodo? (translated above)
- ¿Cómo **te** vas de una fiesta cuando no estás cómodo? (How do you leave a party when you don't feel at ease?)

Summing up:

1. Impersonal use:

   - **Se** va a la plaza por aquí. (= **Uno** va a la plaza por aquí / (Tú) Vas a la plaza por aquí.)
2. Pronominal use:

   - **Se** va del trabajo lo más temprano posible. (He leaves work as early as possible.)
3. Impersonal use + Pronominal use:

In this case, pronominal "se" has preeminence over impersonal "se" (we cannot say "se se"). If both meanings need to be conveyed, "se" is pronominal and "uno" or the second person -- with "te" for pronominal meaning in agreement with "tú" -- is used to make the sentence impersonal:

- **Uno se** va del trabajo lo más temprano posible. (One leaves work as early as possible.)
- (Tú) **Te** vas del trabajo lo más temprano posible. (You leave work as early as possible.)

Comment: `¿Cómo se va uno de una fiesta cuando no está cómodo? ` -> why did you use "uno"? My question is about how to use 2 "se", without substituing one of them with "uno"

Comment: also, if "There is no overlapping of se's", why again did you use "uno" and not 2 "se"? if there's no overlapping

Comment: or did you mean "no overlapping permitted"?

Comment: @roman-voran See if you can understand my answer better now that I've edited it.

Comment: @roman-voran - Right.  It's not permitted.  "Se se" would sound absurd -- so one has to take a different approach, as Gustavson explained. // Gustavson, dewey has a point, there is one more option, *¿Cómo ve voy de una fiesta cuando no estoy cómodo?* (Definitely the least common, though.)

Comment: @aparente001 I understand you meant: *¿Cómo **me** voy de una fiesta cuando no estoy cómodo?* Yes, that works too.

Comment: Right, sorry for the typo, glad you figured out what I meant.